# django entry_set definition

Tags: python, django

I don't understand the following code on page 87 of Practical Django Projects:

from django.views.generic.list_detail import object_list

```
def category_detail(request, slug):
    category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=slug)
    return object_list(request, queryset=category.entry_set.all(),
                       extra_context={ 'category': category }))
```

Where does that `entry_set` come from ? Where has it been defined ? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was [created by the `Entry` model](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects).

> If a model has a `ForeignKey`, instances of the foreign-key model will have access to a `Manager` that returns all instances of the first model. By default, this `Manager` is named `FOO_set`, where `FOO` is the source model name, lowercased.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have my copy in front of me, but the _set property is generally the result of a ForeignKey. The models should look something like:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
  text = models.TextField()
  ...

class Category(models.Model):
  entry = models.ForeignKey(entry)
  ...
```

so if you do a query on the category, each category would have an entry_set which would contain all the data linked through the entry model.